# How is FastAPI query parameter validation implemented in principle?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def func(m: str = Query(max_length=5)):
    return '...'
```

I'm curious about the implementation of parameter validation. Is it done via decorator? I never knew decorators have this style. How does the `Query` function know that it needs to validate the `m` parameter and `m` is a `str` data type?

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

The route decorator (here `@app.get`) analyses the **signature** of your handler function (here `func`). In this case it finds a `Query` object set as the default for parameter `m` and constructs the final request handler function accordingly -- with the constraints defined in `Query`.

Later, when a request comes in, that final request handler function **validates** the query parameters of the request against whatever was defined before, and either lets it through, if it passes validation, or raises an error, if it doesn't.

---

## Details

The following description is based on the public (albeit almost entirely undocumented) interface of the current stable version `0.95.1` of FastAPI. But I noticed before that some of the non-protected functions were modified, moved or trashed altogether, so I guess it would be safer to view most of the following stuff (aside from maybe the `APIRoute` interface) as **implementation details**.

### 1. `APIRoute` construction

When you apply one of those handy little `@app.get` or `@router.post` decorators, a lot of things actually happen under the hood, before the server is even up, and *way* before the first request can come in.

Ultimately that act of decoration will result in a call to [`APIRouter.add_api_route`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L548) (since the other methods like e.g. [`get`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L834) are essentially convenience wrappers around that).

That method will construct an instance of [`APIRoute`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L322) (or a subclass), which receives (among many other things) your endpoint/route handler function (`func` in your example) as an argument and sets it as its `endpoint` attribute. And inside the `APIRoute.__init__` method that handler function will be passed to the [`get_dependant`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L446) function to construct what will later be necessary to validate your requests.

We'll take a look at that next.

### 2. Signature inspection

When you call the [`Query(...)`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/param_functions.py#L46) function, you are constructing a [`Query`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/params.py#L105) object. When you follow the inheritance tree, you'll find that `Query` is ultimately just a subclass of **Pydantic**'s [`FieldInfo`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/fields.py#L97). That is just a bucket to hold all the constraints defined for a model field. This is one of those places, where **FastAPI** is tightly coupled to the **Pydantic** way of doing things.

So, your `func` signature contains a default value for the `m` parameter and that value is of the type `Query`. As mentioned earlier, the route constructor calls [`get_dependant`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L283) passing your `func` as its `call` argument, and `get_dependant` will promptly inspect its signature by calling [`get_typed_signature(call)`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L292).

Now it has access to all the parameters of `func` *including* their default values, which means it has that aforementioned `Query` instance associated with the `m` parameter.

### 3. `ModelField` setup

The `get_dependant` function will construct a [`Dependant`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/models.py#L15) object and then it will iterate over the handler function parameters, get to `m` and call [`analyze_param`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L359) with the info it has on that parameter, which will (among other things) return a Pydantic [`ModelField`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/fields.py#L365) instance for that parameter.

Unlike the simple `FieldInfo` mentioned earlier, the `ModelField` class is *much* more powerful and it implements the **validation** capabilities that are so essential for Pydantic models and that FastAPI cleverly utilizes for request validation.

Towards the end of `get_dependant` the [`add_param_to_fields`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L498) function merely attaches this `ModelField` instance to the `Dependant` object's `query_params` attribute (a list of fields).

It is important to note that the `ModelField` object now already has everything it needs to validate *any* object against the constraints you defined in `Query`. By the way, the **type annotation** for that route handler parameter (here `str`) is also incorporated in the `ModelField` validation logic at this point.

### 4. Request handler setup

The very last step in `APIRoute.__init__` is to set up an ASGI app for that route with all the information gathered up to this point by calling [`request_response(self.get_route_handler())`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L453). The interesting part for us is the `get_route_handler` call though, which is just a convenience wrapper around a call to [`get_request_handler`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L168).

That function takes that previously constructed `Dependant` object as well as many other things. It internally constructs and then returns that inconspicuously named [**`app`**](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L190) function.

But that is where the magic happens. By that I mean that `app` is the function that can be rightfully called the **final request handler**, i.e. it takes a `Request` and it returns a `Response`.

### 5. Request handling

All the previous steps happen, when the module containing your route handler function is **loaded**, i.e. before any request can even begin to be processed. The following describes what happens later on, when a request actually comes.

In one of the stages of the aforementioned final request handler, the [`solve_dependencies`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L546) coroutine is awaited, which takes the `Request` object and our `Dependant` object. There the [`request_params_to_args`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L632) function is called with the `query_parms` list of the `Dependant` (i.e. how the query parameters *should* look) and the request's *actual* query parameters.

And that is where the [`validate`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/dependencies/utils.py#L701) method of each `ModelField` instance is called. This again is **Pydantic** territory and will ensure that the query parameters are of the right type, fit all our constraints, etc.

If no validation errors are encountered, the validated values along with all the rest are passed to **your** handler function (finally!) via [`run_endpoint_function`](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/0.95.1/fastapi/routing.py#L237).

This is how you can be sure, that the string `m` inside `func` will ultimately be no more than `5` characters in length.

Comment: This is really handy and well explained, thanks.